# htaccess, If redirected from specific .php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have got a .htaccess file which isn't working as it should.

This is in my PHP file (access.php)

```
header("Location: https://example.com/images/flower.jpg");
```

This is what I have in my .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png)$">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!https://example\.com/scripts/access\.php" [NC]
RewriteRule https://%{HTTP_HOST}/management/htaccess/access\.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [R]
</FilesMatch>
```

What I want to accomplish:
I only want the https://example.com/images/flower.jpg to work if it was redirected by https://example.com/scripts/access.php. And if it wasn't redirected by access.php, then I want it to go back to access.php.

Comment: That `RewriteRule` is invalid, it violates the syntax: That directive requires _two_ arguments plus flags, you only provided one. That issue will get pointed out in the http server's error log file. You _can not_ develop such an application without monitoring that log file. Here is the documentation of the tool you are trying to use, I suggest you start reading there: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g)$">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ 
RewriteRule ^ /scripts/access\.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example.com/scripts/access\.php [AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^ /scripts/access\.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
</FilesMatch>
```